# JQuery AJAX Cross Domain Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf, cross-domain

I am doing a global development project with a team in another country.

The team will provide the web services on their domain while my client (another domain) will call on their web services.

The first time when I tried to call the web service, we bumped into the same origin policy error and the team has subsequently allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*'.

URL: http://rentit.itu.dk/RentIt03/services/ServiceSmu.svc/account/login

Request Parameters:

1. email: string
2. password: string

Request Type: POST

Response Parameters:

1. success: boolean
2. loginToken: long

We tested the web service using a Simple REST Client (extension on Google Chrome) and it works (first image as shown below).

After which, I attempted to call their web service (code snippet below). However, we had an error 405 method not allowed (second image as shown below).

I have enabled "crossDomain: true" in my code and have specified the same things as the Simple REST Client. I have also tried using JSON.stringify but it is still not working.

Is there something wrong with my codes or is there additional stuffs that have to be added to the web services which was done by the other team?

Thank you!

[image: Simple REST Client]

```
$("#login").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://rentit.itu.dk/RentIt03/services/ServiceSmu.svc/account/login',             
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {email:"email",pw:"password"},
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function(data){            
            successVar = data.success;
            loginToken = data.loginToken;
        } 

    });
});
```

[image: Calling web service via AJAX]

Comment: Usually the browser prevents Cross Site Requests for protection of the user. You may have to proxy the request through your server.

Comment: Hi Re Captcha, I have tried running it from both localhost as well as deployed it to my school server but both doesn't work. When you mean proxy the request through the server, are you referring to the server on my side (client) or the server that belongs to the team that developed the web services? thanks